# How do I change the unknown array depth and change all of the letters from lower to upper in php array？·

Tags: php, arrays

```
$ar = array(10, 102, 199, "a"=>array('B','c','d'=>array('e','f')),'g','h');
```

I want to change all of the lower letters to upper (A B C D E F G H).
I tried this:

```
function toto($arr,$depth='1'){
    $tem=array();
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        if(is_string($value)){
            $tem[]=strtoupper($value);
        }elseif(is_array($value)&&array_depth($value)>1){
            // $J=str_repeat('[]', (array_depth($value)));
            $tem[]=array_map('strtoupper',$value);
        }else{
            $tem[]=$value;
        }
    }
    return $tem;
}
```

And I tried getting the array depth with this:

```
function array_depth($array) {
    $max_depth = 1;

    foreach ($array as $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $depth = array_depth($value) + 1;

            if ($depth > $max_depth) {
                $max_depth = $depth;
            }
        }
    }        
    return $max_depth;
 }
```

How can I achieve these two things?

Comment: You can use `recursion`.

Comment: Saw your blog in myexception and came to vote up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this one-liner:

```
$ar = json_decode(strtoupper(json_encode($ar)),true);
```

first it is encoded to json, then `strtoupper` called and decoded as array again.

This way you will get **both keys and values** uppercased.

Comment: to get the array again, not a JSON string

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps a quick look at the PHP docs would have shown you the [array_walk_recursive()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) function which would let you do:

```
array_walk_recursive(
    $ar,
    function (&$value, $key) {
        $value = strtoupper($value);
    }
);
```

for setting every string at every level of a multi-dimensional to uppercase.... and then you don't even need to know the array depth

Comment: But now since: *i want chage all of them lower to upper A B C **D** E F G H,* , D is a key I'm not too sure if OP also wants the keys in uppercase

Comment: There's no indication of the existing code making any effort to change case of keys; in fact, nothing is being rebuilt in the existing code with any existing key definitions at all

Comment: Yes that's why I wrote: *I'm not too sure*, but D is a key in OP's array (just in lowercase)... Let's see what OP means

Answer (score 0):

using [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) :-

```
function to_upper($n)
{
    return(strtoupper($n));
}

$input = array('a','b','c');
$output = array_map("to_upper", $input);
print_r($output);
```

Comment: thankyou，but the array depth will not known,and the upstairs answers worded.thanks ,all of my unkonwn friends

Comment: @BoTong just sharing the ideas.